# The difference between dense graph and sparse one

Tags: graphs, terminology, landau-notation

How to decide whether the following statement is correct?

O(E log E) and O(E log V) are equivalent regardless whether graph is dense or
sparse

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Which definition of "sparse" are you using?

Comment: @Raphael The question may not be ideal, but I am surprised that you consider the word "sparse" to be unclear in this context. The word "sparse" is widely used in mathematics, and it is normally not considered a problem that it can mean slightly different things in different contexts. For example, a Toeplitz matrix is sparse, even so its corresponding (bipartite) graph is dense. But I don't see how any confusion could arise in the context of this question.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel I'm not a big fan of promoting imprecision just because it "usually doesn't matter". For graphs in particular different notions of "sparse" exist and may cause different answers here, unless we discuss only connected graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with your definitions. For any graph, the number of nodes and the number of edges is a constant, so $O(V) = O(E) = (1)$. This is clearly not helpful.

*Sparse* and *dense* only make sense for a *family* of graphs $\{G_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

The edge density of a graph $G$ is the proportion of possible edges that a graph actually has:

$$ D = \frac{|E(G)|}{{|V(G)|}\choose{2}}. $$

The edge density of a family of graphs is

$$ D = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|E(G_n)|}{{|V(G_n)|}\choose{2}}. $$

The family is *sparse* if $D = 0$ and *dense* if $D > 0$. You must analyze the performance of your algorithm under either type of family as inputs.

This definition is from Diestel's *Graph Theory*.

Answer (score -1):

> In mathematics, a dense graph is a graph in which the number of edges
>   is close to the maximal number of edges. The opposite, a graph with
>   only a few edges, is a sparse graph.

A **sparse graph** is a graph $G=(V,E)$ in which $|E|=O(|V|)$.

For example, consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ with n nodes. Suppose that the out-degree of each vertex in $G$ is some fixed constant k. Graph $G$ is a sparse graph because $|E|=k|V|=O(|V|)$.

**[UPDATE]** If $N$ and $E$ are the number of nodes and edges in a network respectively. $N^2$ possible edges in a fully connected network.

Sparseness $P = \frac{E} {N^2} $

If $P << 1$, then the network is sparse.

Source: [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://youtu.be/zJTVMkGe8-8?t=3m27s)

A **dense graph** is a graph $G=(V,E)$ in which $|E|=O(|V|^2)$.

For example, consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ with n nodes. $|E|=f|V|^2=O(|V|^2)$.

> How to decide whether the following statement is correct?
>
> O(E log E) and O(E log V) are equivalent regardless whether graph is
>   dense or sparse

In the case of $O(E log E)$ and $O(E log V)$,

asymptotically $log E \approx log V$ and only $E$ contributes to the result regardless the graph is dense or sparse.

Thus, 
$O(E log E) \approx O(E log V)$ for any dense or sparse graph.

Comment: You want to use some $\Omega$s there.

Comment: "asymptotically log E ≈ log V" -- not always; consider $E \in O(\log V)$. "only E contributes" -- so you propose we always ignore logarithmic factors?

Comment: Raphael has a point; you need lower bounds to make these definitions meaningful. If we have a family of graphs where $|E|=O(|V|)$ then it will also be the case that $|E|=O(|V|^2)$, so by your definitions, every graph would be dense.

Comment: @Raphael thanks for the insight. Yes, when $E \epsilon O(logV)$, the graph is mostly disconnect and this solution wont work. Feel free to edit my solution.

Comment: "A sparse graph is a graph $G=(V,E)$ in which $|E|=O(|V|)$." It doesn't make sense to write that about a single graph: there is no such thing as "for all large enough $|V|$" when you're talking about a single graph. Density and sparsity are properties of _families_ of graphs, not single graphs.

Comment: "If $P\ll 1$ then the graph is sparse." What does that even mean? Is 0.01 "much less than" 1? What about 0.1? Whatever number you're prepared to accept as indicating sparsity (let's say, 0.0001), this definition accepts infinite families of graphs $G_1, G_2, \dots$ with $|E(G_n)| = \Theta(|V(G_n)|^2)$ as being sparse, which is not the standard definition.